# How to use the generated JWT token in all the pages for authentication

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.4

I have generated token using JWT Authentication. Next what should I do to authenticate in all the pages like if I haven't logged in and if move to other page then it should authenticate to loggin. Please tell what should I do next after generating the JWT authentication token.

Here is my code to generate to JWT token

```
public function authenticate(Request $request)
{
    //$userinfo=DB::connection('mysqll')->table('register')->select('_id','fname','lname','username','password','email','mobileno')->get();
    $userinfo=DB::connection('mysql')->table('register')->select('id','fname','lname','username','password','email','mobileno','created_at')->first();

    //$credentials = JWTAuth::fromUser($userinfo);

    // grab credentials from the request
    //$credentials = $request->only('name','password');

    try {

        //$token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials);
        //dd($token);
        // attempt to verify the credentials and create a token for the user
        if (!$token = JWTAuth::fromUser($userinfo)) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'invalid_credentials'], 401);
        }
    } catch (JWTException $e) {
        // something went wrong whilst attempting to encode the token
        return response()->json(['error' => 'could_not_create_token'], 500);
    }

    // all good so return the token
    return response()->json(compact('token'));
}
```

And Token is

```
{"token":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjEsImlzcyI6Imh0dHA6XC9cL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo4MDAwXC9hcGlcL2F1dGhlbnRpY2F0ZSIsImlhdCI6MTQ5MDE4NTYxNSwiZXhwIjoxNDkwMTg5MjE1LCJuYmYiOjE0OTAxODU2MTUsImp0aSI6ImJiOTZjNzQyNzVhOTliYmQxM2I1ZjQxZDcwMGIwMGE2In0.hwqnwtRSOLGSMhHJMufFKdp7CPz6nlhhiVL5sePIDZw"}
```

Now what is the next step to authenticate if I move to other page without loggin.

Comment: Laravel 5.4 has a middleware for that. You do not need to take care of that.

Comment: please tel me how to use that. what I need to do

Comment: Please check the documentation here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passport